# Ошибка 404 на github pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Не могу понять почему не отображается сайт. Залил файлы на созданный репозиторий с именем вида имя.github.io Все успешно залил но при переходе на гит пейдж ошибка 404 при том что файл index.html лежит в корне. В чем может быть проблема?

Если создавать пустую страницу с надписью ПРИВЕТ МИР, то всё работает. Если загружать полный проект, не работает.

Comment: Что у вас за проект? Готовый статический сайт или исходники для Jekyll?

Comment: В [другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/696570/181472) нашел ваш предполагаемый репозиторий: maximchizhikov.github.io. Так вот, пользователя https://github.com/maximchizhikov на гитхабе нет. Вы точно свое имя пользователя ввели?

Comment: Пользователь у меня senekisi, но репозиторий именно так называется.
Я пробовал создавать репозиторий с таким же именем, как и мой логин, а именно: senekisi.github.io... все равно не получается :)

Comment: Почему-то сейчас заработало. Может гитхаб долго обновлял и внедрял рабочий сайт? Странно, у меня на локалке все прекрасно работает, на гите небольшие косяки с позиционкой, интересно почему...